# php convert absolute URL containing relative paths in absolute url without relative path

Tags: php, url, path

I have a simple strange problem but I can not find a function to do this after many search.

I have an URL like `http://example.com/folder/folder2/../image/test.jpg` and I would like a function which return the correct absolute link:

```
http://example.com/folder/image/test.jpg
```

A function with only one param, the url (and not base dir or relative dir like in examples I found)

If you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a starting point:

```
<?php
function unrelatify($url)
{
    $parts     = parse_url($url);
    $path      = $parts['path'] ?? '';
    $hierarchy = explode('/', $path);

    while(($key = array_search('..', $hierarchy)) !== false) {
        if($key-1 > 0)
            unset($hierarchy[$key-1]);
        unset($hierarchy[$key]);
        $hierarchy = array_values($hierarchy);
    }
    $new_path = implode('/', $hierarchy);

    return str_replace($path, $new_path, $url);
}

echo unrelatify('http://example.com/../folder/../folder2/../image/test.jpg#foo?bar=baz');
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/image/test.jpg#foo?bar=baz
```

You may want to see how browsers and other web clients de-relativify (urls).

Comment: Please try and break this.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone for your answers.

here are a recap and  some other ways i've tested

```
            <?php

            function unrelatify($url) {
                $parts = parse_url($url);
                $path = $parts['path'];
                $hierarchy = explode('/', $path);

                while (($key = array_search('..', $hierarchy)) !== false) {
                    if ($key - 1 > 0)
                        unset($hierarchy[$key - 1]);
                    unset($hierarchy[$key]);
                    $hierarchy = array_values($hierarchy);
                }
                $new_path = implode('/', $hierarchy);

                return str_replace($path, $new_path, $url);
            }

            function normalizePath($path) {
                do {
                    $path = preg_replace(
                            array('#//|/\./#', '#/([^/.]+)/\.\./#'), '/', $path, -1, $count
                    );
                } while ($count > 0);
                return str_replace('../', '', $path);
            }

            function processUrl($url) {
                $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
                $path = $parsedUrl['path'];
                $pathSegments = explode("/", $path);
                $iterator = 0;
                $removedElements = 0;
                foreach ($pathSegments as $segment) {
                    if ($segment == "..") {
                        if ($iterator - $removedElements - 1 < 0) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        unset($pathSegments[$iterator - $removedElements - 1]);
                        unset($pathSegments[$iterator]);
                        $removedElements += 2;
                    }
                    $iterator++;
                }

                $parsedUrl['path'] = implode("/", $pathSegments);

                $newUrl = $parsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $parsedUrl['host'] . "/" . $parsedUrl['path'];

                return $newUrl;
            }

            function path_normalize($path) {
                $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
                $blocks = preg_split('#/#', $path, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                $res = array();

                while (list($k, $block) = each($blocks)) {
                    switch ($block) {
                        case '.':
                            if ($k == 0)
                                $res = explode('/', path_normalize(getcwd()));
                            break;
                        case '..';
                            if (!$res)
                                return false;
                            array_pop($res);
                            break;
                        default:
                            $res[] = $block;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                $r = implode('/', $res);

                return $r;
            }

            echo 'path_normalize<br />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/modules/newsletters/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . path_normalize($url);


            echo '<hr />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . path_normalize($url);


            echo '<hr />normalizePath<br />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/modules/newsletters/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . normalizePath($url);


            echo '<hr />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . normalizePath($url);


            echo '<hr />unrelatify<br />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/modules/newsletters/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . unrelatify($url);


            echo '<hr />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . unrelatify($url);


            echo '<hr />processUrl<br />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/modules/newsletters/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . processUrl($url);


            echo '<hr />';
            $url = 'http://www.example.com/../../images/homeslider-images/test-5.jpg';
            echo $url . ' === > ' . processUrl($url);
            ?>
```